# Error while parsing HTML with PHP

Tags: php, xml, parsing

I'm trying to parse some HTML.
This is my code:

```
xml_parse_into_struct($p, $initpage, $values);
foreach ($values as $key => $val) {
    if (($val['tag'] == 'INPUT') && ($val['attributes']['name'] == 'authenticity_token')) {
        $token = $val['attributes']['value'];
        break;
    }
}
echo $token;
```

No problems with the curl or the XML parsing... I know that $values includes the goodies, as `print_r($values)` wil output, amongst other things, this:

> ```
> [48] => Array
>    (
>        [tag] => INPUT
>        [type] => complete
>        [level] => 8
>        [attributes] => Array
>             (
>                 [NAME] => authenticity_token
>                 [TYPE] => hidden
>                 [VALUE] => d76a4bec329537ac3322
>             )
>
>     )
> ```

When I try running the code, however, I get this error:

> PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: token in /media/.sda3/pjotr/scripts/tweet.php on line 49

Answer (score 2):

Keys are case sensitive. You check for `name`, which doesn't match `NAME`. Same goes for `value`, of course, so you need to fix that too.